# How to fix invalid indexer on magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, reindex, shell

I am new with Magento, is my first time with this software and I need a little support.

I have installed Magento in AMPPS of my mac, but in dashboard appears a warning with the ne

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.

I´ve looked for the solution to this and it says, execute the next script on shell:

> bin/magento indexer:reindex

I ready go to my shell and I´ve executed this command but is not working.

[image]

I need "go to the CLI and then the root folder of your magento installation and run the below command"...

but I don´t know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange :). You are running your command in Magento Root Folder? Example: `D:\wamp\www\magento2>php bin/magento indexer:reindex`?

Comment: Thank you Ankit Shah. Yes, I am running command from Magento Root folder is  mymagento. Now, the error is: Parse error: parse error in /Applications/AMPPS/www/mymagento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Comment: Run following command as order `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php bin/magento cache:flush`, `chmod -R 777 var pub`, `rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this command from your magento root folder.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely to be a permissions issue.
You can issue command `sudo chmod u+x bin/magento` and then run

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If still unable to run command then check the ownership of files is correctly setup, you can run

```
sudo chown -R user:group .
```

from magento root directory.

Comment: Thank you Devtype, but this not working . . .  command not found :(

Comment: Please ensure you use correct user and user group in command chown -R user:group .

Answer (score 0):

First you go to shop root in terminal comments.

To give full permission for your shop system, And run below mention commnet in *shop root directory*:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

Now change the permission. So execute below mention comments in *shop root directory* for reindex:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Please check in this method, solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you Sankar_k, I´ve changed permission but now, the error is: Parse error: parse error in /Applications/AMPPS/www/mymagento.local/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93